# Setting environments when running tests

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I am struggling to find the most convenient solution to specify environment when running tests via commandline. Ideally i would like to have environments specified in a file e.g.:

```
dev = 'http://dev.com'
staging = 'http://staging.com'
```

As far as i am aware, it is impossible to use custom parameters in rspec like this:

```
rspec tests --env 'dev'
```

So the main question would be, what are the best practices to set and change environments when starting the test suite?

Comment: Hmm this looks like you run tests against an external system. May I suggest using a library like [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock)?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this would be with an environment variable.

```
TEST_ENV=dev rspec tests
```

and then in your test setup you can access `ENV['TEST_ENV']` to determine what settings you want to use - (If using rails the environment variable to use would be RAILS_ENV)